# "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value:"

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel, making reply functions.
I would appreciate it if you could fix this code.

I got this error:

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '<div>da</div>' for column 'content' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `replies` (`content`, `discussion_ ▶"
```

2019_07_26_035335_create_replies_table.php
This is how my table looks:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRepliesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('replies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('discussion_id');
            $table->integer('content');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('replies');
    }
}
```

RepliesController.php

```php
namespace LaravelForum\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


// 2019/07/29
// C:\laravel-apps\bulletin-board\app\Http\Requests\CreateReplyRequest.php
use LaravelForum\Http\Requests\CreateReplyRequest;

// postscript 
use LaravelForum\Discussion;


class RepliesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(CreateReplyRequest $request, Discussion $discussion)
    {
        // C:\laravel-apps\bulletin-board\app\Http\Requests\CreateReplyRequest.php
        auth()->user()->replies()->create([
            'content' => $request->content ,
            'discussion_id' => $discussion->id
        ]);

        session()->flash('success', 'Reply added');

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

C:\laravel-apps\bulletin-board\app\Reply.php

```php
<?php

namespace LaravelForum;

class Reply extends Model
{
    //
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
    public function discussion()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Discussion::class);
    }
}
```

C:\laravel-apps\bulletin-board\app\Http\Requests\CreateReplyRequest.php

```php
<?php

namespace LaravelForum\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateReplyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
            'content' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to insert in a integer column? string??

Answer (score 0):

you are using `$table->integer('content');` interger value for content column. instead of using integer value use `$table->text('content');` for the content. As i felt you are refering reply body as content.

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions.
I rewrote that code. However, I still got the error.

Comment: public function up()
{
Schema::create('replies', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->integer('discussion_id');
$table->text('content');
$table->timestamps();
});
}

Comment: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '<div>helllo</div>' for column 'content' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `replies` (`content`, `discuss ▶"

Comment: after rewriting the code did you run `php artisan migrate:fresh` command?

Comment: Now, I can't open Channel dropdown menus on the bottom, And list on the left disappears.
Do you have any ideas?